# Rendering graphviz plots in GUI using python

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I'm wondering if anyone has advice or can direct me to information about how to render a graphviz or pygraphviz plot in a GUI. I'm generating ROS-like nodal plots using python and ideally I'd like to allow a user to interact with them. Thank you!

Comment: Interact how? I mean,  for rendering in a GUI you can just output a PNG or SVG file and then display it using whatever default image viewer is available (or just load it in a web browser).

Comment: Basically so the user can select whether they want to display certain information overlaid on various nodes